# Class loading issue for a Buggy Jar

Tags: java, deployment, jar, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

**Short Question**

I have the same class (fully qualified com.example.pkg.cls.ClassName) in a jar and my web application code base. When my application loads, I want to load the class in my Web application instead of the one at the jar in classpath.

How should I do that?

**Long Question**

I have a situation like this here:

I have a web application with a JAR `A` as a dependency. The jar is a third party jar (some Amazon SDK). JAR `A` has a dependency on JAR `B` (some commons-lang).

Recently I upgraded the Web application to run Java 11 from Java 7. There is some bug in JAR B which is failing a code flow (specific to Java 11, tries to parse the java.version string). I have already checked for different versions of JAR A which might fix the problem but it doesn't. Infact, JAR A is deprecated and is no more available.

The part that is failing in JAR B is a `toString` method and in JAR A is a `log` statement. I am totally ok if that toString method doesn't return anything or returns a blank String.

After trying multiple solutions over days, I have been suggested to do this:

1 - Write a class with the same fully qualified class name as the failing class in B, copy the code and change the `toString` method.

2 - Load the class explicitly at startup, so that when the API is hit my class is already loaded over the class inside JAR B.

I have two questions here:

1 - Is there a problem with this approach?

2 - How can I load a class in my own project. Can anyone provide a code sample for this.

Comment: If you can put your fixed JAR on the classpath before JARs A and B, when Java loads that class, it'll load the one from the fixed JAR. Or you can just edit the JARs A and B.

Comment: Actually what  I am trying to do is, at startup explicitly load the fixed class so that it is available. There are two options, put the fixed class in a jar and load the fixed jar or write the fixed class in my project. I am trying to do the second one and not create and load the jar file

Comment: Creating a fixed version of the class and replacing it with the bugged version directly in the jar is the best solution I think.

Comment: @Guillaume Oh, is it possible to replace the bugged version directly in the jar. How should I do that at runtime.

Comment: The bugged version is present in JAR B which is a dependency of JAR A. JAR A is maven dependency in my application, so it brings JAR B alongside from maven. So even if I fix jar B replacing the class file, it will again be replaced sometime later

Comment: If you're using maven you need to manually create a patched version of the jar, publish it in a repo (e.g. your local repo or an internal Nexus repo) and modify your pom.xml to require the patched version of the jar.

Comment: @mickeymoon You wouldn't do it at runtime, you'd just fix the jar file itself.

Comment: @user253751 I get your point but it's a pain point to add the jar in the artifactory and fetch it from there. The artifactory is an internal repository, but yeah that's a viable solution if nothing better works.

Comment: Also, how do I get create the fixed class file to be updated in the jar file. Because the code in the buggy class references other classes in the jar. Should I write a new jar, include the original jar as a dependency in my new jar (in provided scope) and compile it and then use the generated class file to replace from the original jar?

Comment: if that jar is open source you might be able to rebuild it from sources

Comment: Ok, I guess it should be open sourced, apache commons lang 2.6 it is. So I can download the source make code changes and build the new jar, right?

Comment: yes that should be a good solution. please note that from a licensing perspective you're entering a gray area

Comment: Can you shed more light to the gray area? Pun intended :), but can you let me know what could be the issue and how can I overcome that.

Comment: I patched the jar file. Created the class file by copying over the culprit class code with the same fully qualified class name in my current project and building it. That created the class file and then I patched the jar using the same class file.